# Automapper and Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, automapper

I had two problem with Automapper and Entity Framework and I would like to know if my solutions are the best one.

Context :

I have an `ObjectA` which has a list of `ObjectB` which in turn has an `ObjectC`.

`ObjectC` is a list in the database, like countries. I can change `ObjectC` on `ObjectB` but I don't add want to add `ObjectC`.

I use MVVM and `ObjectB` is listed in a datagrid. There are comboboxes to choose `ObjectC`.

I would like to save `ObjectA` and `ObjectB` at the same time so I use Automapper and a transaction.

```
    public void SaveObjectA(ObjectA p_ObjectA)
    {
        OpenTransaction();

        var l_Provider = new DataProvider<DB.ObjectA>(Context);
        var l_ObjectA = l_Provider.FindById(p_ObjectA.ID);

        Mapper.Map(p_ObjectA, l_ObjectA);

        CloseTransaction();
    }
```

Entity Framework classes :

```
public partial class ObjectA
{
    public ObjectA()
    {
        this.ObjectB = new HashSet<ObjectB>();
    }

    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectB { get; set; }
} 

public partial class ObjectB
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid ObjectCID { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectC ObjectC { get; set; }
}

public partial class ObjectC
{
    public System.Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

DTO classes :

```
public class ObjectA : ObjectBase
{
    public ObjectA ()
    {
        ObjectB = new Collection< ObjectB >();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ObjectB> ObjectB { get; set; }
}

public class ObjectB : ObjectBase
{
    private ObjectC  _ObjectC { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectC ObjectC
    {
        get
        {
            return _ObjectC;
        }
        set
        {
            _ObjectC = value;
        }
    }
}

public class ObjectC : ObjectBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public abstract class ObjectBase
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
}
```

**1st problem**: when I save `ObjectB`, Entity Framework tries to insert `ObjectC`. But `ObjectC` already exists. I don’t want an insert but an update.

My solution (seen on forums) :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectB, DB.ObjectB>()
      .ForMember(pro=>pro.ObjectC, opt=>opt.Ignore());
```

But I don’t understand because if I ignore `ObjectC`, `ObjectC` shouldn’t update. However, it works (ie : update ok and he doesn’t try to add a row in database and Automapper/EF can find `ObjectC` in database and update `ObjectCID` on `ObjectB`...)

Note: it works too with the solution of the first point of my 2nd problem.

**2nd problem**: when I update, add or delete a row on my datagrid, I would like to save changes in database.

- Update : Same problem than the first one : the row already exist.

  ```
  Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectB, DB.ObjectB>()
        .ConstructUsing(s => Context.Set<DB.ObjectB>().Find(s.ID));
  ```

  I think, the solution is to attach the correct row from the database and then fill the properties.

  So I use `ConstructUsing` to find the row.
- Add : Then, IDs are null and I can't save new line

  ```
  Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectB, DB.ObjectB>()
        .ConstructUsing(s => Context.Set<DB.ObjectB>().Find(s.ID) ?? 
                                 Context.Set<DB.ObjectB>().Create())
  ```

  In the case where the row doesn’t exist, I have to create (and attach) an object to the context.
- Delete : row deleted on datagrid are not deleted in database :

  ```
  Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectA, DB.ObjectA>()
        .ConstructUsing(s => Context.Set<DB.ObjectA>().Create())
        .AfterMap
        (
            (bef, aft) => aft.ObjectB.ToList()
                .Where(x => !bef.ObjectB.Select(z=>z.ID).Contains(x.ID))
                .ToList()
                .ForEach(ele => Context.ObjectB
                                       .Remove(Context.ObjectB.Find(ele.ID)))
        );
  ```

So, it works but I wonder how you would have done, an easier way.

Comment: You slimmed down the code for clarity (which is good) but does the real `ObjectB` have an `ObjectCID` property? Another comment would be that I wouldn't use AutoMapper when the mapping becomes "complex" (where you draw the line is a matter of taste), although that doesn't explain anything.

Comment: Yes  `ObjectB` have an `ObjectCID` property. this is the code generated by EF. It's the name of the foreign key and EF create a property.

Comment: I mean the DTO class... maybe you should use different names :)

Comment: Sorry. No, I don't add the properties for the foreign key in my POCO objects. I probably made ​​a mistake by saying DTO. I mean that are objects used to send to the UI

Comment: Use a suffix like ObjectAVM (ViewModel)

Answer (score 0):

Well, before I dig into your questions, let me just star by quoting something from Autommaper [docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki):

> Currently, AutoMapper is geared towards model projection scenarios to flatten complex object models to DTOs and other simple objects, whose design is better suited for serialization, communication, messaging, or simply an anti-corruption layer between the domain and application layer

That said, if you read carefully, automapper was designed for converting from complex objects to simpler ones, or reading between the lines, from Entity Objects to Pocos, DTOs, ViewModels, etc... Not the other way around. Why? simply because it is too complex. It's not a situation on you can just have a `new ObjectA()`.

Question 1:
That's the expected behavior from Entity Framework (and other mainstream Orms). EF handles with Entity Objects. If you specify that ObjectC Property is a new entity, EF will try to insert it. If you want to use one that exists, you need to load it first from the context, or simply use the ObjectCId foreign key.

Question 2:
It's really almost same answer as Question 1. EF was design for you to work with entity objects. When you modify them EF track the changes and then after you call `SaveChanges()`, those are persisted on Database.

Just a special remark about the Delete. EF doesn't cascade delete, like "cascade=all-delete-orphan" on NHibernate. There are some [workarounds](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/05/08/missing-ef-feature-workarounds-cascade-delete-orphans/), but in general, you'll need to manage the delete of the child when you want to delete the entire relation.

I know that this isn't probably the answer you were looking for, but you're running on issues that are being raised because you're not using the tools right.

General speaking, working with EF is simple as:

1 - Load entities from database

2 - modify them

3 - apply changes on database by calling `SaveChanges()`